# Adding the root element to a xml document in java

Tags: java, xml, dom

I'm trying  to generate a XML file and save it. The following code shows the way i append root element to the document. When i do this an exception was thrown as follows.

**Exception in thread "main" org.w3c.dom.DOMException: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: An attempt was made to insert a node where it is not permitted.**

```
public void comUnitIterator() {
    System.out.println("This is the iterator");
    Document fileDeclarationDocument = documentBuilder();
    if (comUnits != null && comUnits.size() > 0) {

        for (int i=0; i<comUnits.size();i++) {
            CompilationUnit cu=comUnits.get(i);
            SourceCodeClassVisitor classVisitor = new SourceCodeClassVisitor();
            ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration classOrInterface = classVisitor.visit(cu, null);
            Element rootElement = fileDeclarationDocument.createElement("class");
            fileDeclarationDocument.appendChild(rootElement);
            //classVisitor.visit(cu, null);
        }
    }
    createXML(fileDeclarationDocument, "ABC");
}
```

Can someone please tell me the reason for this exception.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could try using JDOM, DOM is a bit long winded and problematic in Java. http://www.jdom.org/

Answer (score 2):

You're adding a root element for every iteration of this loop:

`for (int i=0; i<comUnits.size();i++)`

Change your code to something like:

```
Element rootElement = fileDeclarationDocument.createElement("class");
fileDeclarationDocument.appendChild(rootElement);
for (int i=0; i<comUnits.size();i++) {
     //add children here
 }
```

There can only be one root element

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a *single* root element. Currently you're creating one for each element of `comUnits`. You should pull this statement:

```
Element rootElement = fileDeclarationDocument.createElement("class");
```

... and append it to the document:

```
fileDeclarationDocument.appendChild(rootElement);
```

Then in your loop, you can create a new element for each iteration, and append *that* to the root element. (It's not really clear what you want your XML structure to be, to be honest. With more details on that, we may be able to help you more.)